# Reversing rodata

Tags: ida, c, unknown-data

I'm playing with an ELF binary to learn IDA, and I'm not sure how to interpret what I'm seeing..

A function calls this:

```
v1 = MList[2 * result];
```

When I look at MList, it looks like this:

```
public MList
MList          dd 12Fh
dd offset M1
db  30h ; 0
db    1
db    0
db    0
offset M2
db  31h ; 1
db    1
db    0
db    0
dd offset M3
db  32h ; 2
db    1
db    0
db    0
...
```

Each of the `M*`s looks like this:

```
public M2
M2 db  0Ch
db    0
db    0
db    0
db    1
```

So what exactly is MList? I'm guessing some kind of global table or something, but I can't make heads or tails of what it is. What would this be in regular C code?

Comment: The pseudocode doesn't show a call, though ... unless it'd be a class and it calls `operator[]()`, say. But to the best of my knowledge IDA and Hex-Rays do not yet offer this sort of functionality. Either way, what I typically do is to try and find code that acts on (i.e. reads or writes) the data. It's practically the only way one can make sense of types during static RCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MList  seems to be an array of 8-byte structures. Observe how it contains:

1. a dword (4 bytes)
2. an offset (4 bytes)
3. 4 bytes
4. an offset
5. (repeat)

So it's probably something like:

```
struct mlist_item
{
 int  number;
 int  *arr; 
};

mlist_item MList[];
```

Comment: That was my guess as well, so glad to know I'm not way off-base.. I should have included that I'm finding this in rodata, does that impact anything? Is it just a const or something that's a read-only lookup or does that impact what it would really be?

Answer (score 1):

The notation is an access of array member.
Without more context deciphering the type of `MList` would be a guess game.
`MList` *could be* `int`, `byte`, `char`, `pointer`, or some other complex type.

So for example it could be `int MList[0x10]` and accessing this with a variable expression `2* result` where value of result is "1" would yield every second member of the array.

```
v1 = MList[0x10} = {0,1,2,3,,,,16};
```

with `result = 1` so `MList[2*result] == MList[2] == 2;` and so `v1` in this case would be 2.

From the looks of data `MList` appears to be a structure so first you need to decipher the type and modify the data `MList` before guessing the result of `v1`.